# @Cacheable() returning id null

Tags: spring, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache

I have a method `findAll()` that returns all the speciality from BD, in this method i put the annotation `@Cacheable` to get the data from the cache, the problem is when i execute the `/specialities` api, the first time i get the correct data, when i execute the api the second time i get the data with null ids

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = ServiceConstant.SPECIALITY)
public class SpecialityServiceImpl implements SpecialityService {

    @Autowired
    private SpecialitySearchRepository specialitySearchRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SpecialtyMapper specialityMapper;

    @Override
    @Cacheable
    public List<SpecialityDTO> findAll() {
        return specialitySearchRepository.findAll().stream().map(specialityMapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    }

}

@RestController
public class SpecialityResource {

    @Autowired
    private SpecialityService specialityService;

    @GetMapping("/specialities")
    public List<SpecialityDTO> getAllSpecialitys() {
        return specialityService.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private static final String HAZELCAST_LOGGING_TYPE = "hazelcast.logging.type";

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        return new Config().setInstanceName("cache")
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig().setName(ServiceConstant.SPECIALITY)
                                .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU).setTimeToLiveSeconds(100))
                .setProperty(HAZELCAST_LOGGING_TYPE, "none");
    }

}
```

Comment: Paste also your cache config, might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

@Aymen Kanzari, please see: https://gist.github.com/gokhanoner/766a1a807744d1a69c6a7799c3f34d73

I tried to replicate the issue but it seems working as expected. I can see `inside findAll method` for the first call but next ones just hit the Hazelcast cache. Can you describe the issue a bit more?